# Optimizing python dataframe iteration loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have two dataframes, df and ct

**df**: `UNIT, START, END, CHECK` are relevant columns. CHECK values are all defaulted to 'n'. My code tests them and if they pass changes this value to 'y'

```
df.shape = 59155, 5
```

|  | UNIT | DTHours | START | END | CHECK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A7000 | 0.1097 | 43100.0321 | 43382.1417 | n |
| 1 | A7000 | 0.0125 | 43105.6621 | 43382.6736 | n |
| 2 | A7000 | 0.2042 | 43200.1214 | 43388.3465 | n |
| 3 | A7000 | 0.1521 | 43389.2979 | 43854.4500 | n |
| 4 | A7002 | 0.1455 | 44198.5049 | 44199.0009 | n |

**ct**: `UNIT, START, END` are unique combinations, but each UNIT can have multiple entries (these are effectively start/end dates). On average each UNIT row repeats ~5 times

```
ct.shape = 6219, 3
```

|  | UNIT | START | END |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A7000 | 43101 | 43156 |
| 1 | A7000 | 43101 | 43173 |
| 2 | A7000 | 43172 | 43616 |
| 3 | A7000 | 43172 | 43712 |
| 4 | A7002 | 43172 | 44196 |

I am testing if the values df['START'] and df['END '] are in between any of the instances of that UNIT in ct. However the code is taking exceptionally long. It has iterated through ~12000 rows in 12 hours. What am I doing wrong?

Pseudocode:

```
 for loop iterating through all rows of df
      create list of all cf[START] values for current df[UNIT]
      create list of all cf[END] values for current df[UNIT]

      test if the df[CHECK] value is 'n' viz default value
           for loop iterating over length of cf[START] (len = cf[END]), index
                test if (df[START]>= cf[START][index]) AND (df[END]>= cf[END][index])
                     change df[CHECK] to 'y'
                     break for loop iterating over cf[START] for this row in df
```

**Actual code:**

```py
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    display.clear_output(wait=True)
    display.display(plt.gcf())
    
    df_unit = row['UNIT']
    ct_start = ct.loc[ct['UNIT'] == df_unit]['START'].values
    ct_end = ct.loc[ct['UNIT'] == df_unit]['END'].values
    
    if (row['UNIT'] != 'y'):
        for ct_index in range(len(ct_start)):
            if ((row['START'] >= ct_start[ct_index]) & (row['END'] <= 
ct_end[ct_index])):
                row['CHECK'] == 'y'
                aaa += 1
                break
        
    plt.scatter(index,aaa, c='r')
```

**Expected Output** for the dataframes above

|  | UNIT | DTHours | START | END | CHECK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A7000 | 0.1097 | 43100.0321 | 43382.1417 | n |
| 1 | A7000 | 0.0125 | 43105.6621 | 43382.6736 | n |
| 2 | A7000 | 0.2042 | 43200.1214 | 43388.3465 | y |
| 3 | A7000 | 0.1521 | 43389.2979 | 43854.4500 | n |
| 4 | A7002 | 0.1455 | 44198.5049 | 44199.0009 | n |

Comment: Please include your expected output for the given sample dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb: 90% of the time if you are using a loop on a dataframe, you are doing something wrong

In your case:

- rather than doing `for ... if`, it might be a good idea to filter the dataframe: `df[df["CHECK"] == "y"]`
- you are constantly filtering the `ct` dataframe, for EACH row. You are better off grouping this dataframe once and transforming that into a dictionary that you can access by unit:

  - `units = dict(list(ct.groupby("UNIT")))`
  - `for index in units[df_unit]: do_something()`

This should already considerably improve the performance

Answer (score 0):

We can approach the problem using the following steps

- Reset the index of `df` and `merge` it with `ct` on `UNIT`
- Query the resulting merged dataframe to find the indices where the corresponding values in `START` and `END` satisfies the condition of inclusion
- Using boolean indexing with `loc` update the values in `CHECK` column to `y` using the indices obtained in previous step

```
s  = df.reset_index().merge(ct, on='UNIT', suffixes=['', '_r'])
ix = s.query("START >= START_r and END <= END_r")['index']
df.loc[df.index.isin(ix), 'CHECK'] = 'y'
```

---

```
    UNIT  DTHours       START         END CHECK
0  A7000   0.1097  43100.0321  43382.1417     n
1  A7000   0.0125  43105.6621  43382.6736     n
2  A7000   0.2042  43200.1214  43388.3465     y
3  A7000   0.1521  43389.2979  43854.4500     n
4  A7002   0.1455  44198.5049  44199.0009     n
```